# Accessing .Net Controls in an iFrame from Parent Codebehind

Tags: asp.net, iframe, code-behind

I have a .aspx page with an iframe:

```
<iframe src="SearchAdv.aspx" id="advSearch" runat="server" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="500px;" ></iframe>
```

The iFrame points to an aspx page that has several controls I need to access, example:

```
<asp:dropdownlist id=ddColumn1 runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Width="270px" onselectedindexchanged="ddColumn1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:dropdownlist>
```

I need to get the value of the dropdown list that's in the iFrame from the parent codebehind. I've tried the following but get a null reference error:

```
DropDownList DDCol1 = (DropDownList)advSearch.FindControl("ddColumn1");
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not possible as such. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: its better to use user control buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going to have to call some javascript and pass back to parent as any attempt to read the value from the parents code-behind will give you nothing, you will be reading the value of a freshly instantiated version of your page and not the one thats displaying...

So, in terms of a workflow..

1) Your iFrame drop down gets selected (remove the autopostback from this list)

2) This calls a javascript function in that iframes page.

3) the iFrame page javascript can call the parent window - something like `parent.window.functionName(yourListValue);`

4) Your parent frame should contain the `functionName(val)` which will receive the call from the iFrame window.

5) your Parents `functionName(val)` can now pass the data to itself, either by way of Ajax or perhaps first populating an `<asp:hidden` field with the passed in value and then triggering one of your `<asp:button` controls, then you can catch the value in your codebehind of your parent page.

Sounds long winded, though its' simple enough once you get going.